# How to dump an std::unordered_multimap<uint, T> to a std::vector<T>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, iterator

I am trying to go from a `std::unordered_multimap<uint, T> lookup` to a `std::vector<T> v`

So far I tried

```
std::vector<T> v(lookup.begin(), lookup.end());
```

but it obviously doesn't work since the resulting iterators of `begin()` and `end()` are of type `pair<uint, T>`, so what would be the fastest correct way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you guaranty that there are no *hole* in indexes ? or `uint` values are discarded ?

Comment: No, there can be empty buckets.

Comment: You can just loop over the map and `push_back` the `T`s into the vector. You can also write a wrapper around the map iterator that returns the `T` instead of the `pair<uint, T>` when dereferenced.

Comment: So what should be the content of the vector in this place ? default `T` ?

Comment: I want v to contain all the T values stored inside my multimap

Comment: @Jarod42, I don't think OP expects that the vector indices have the same mapping as the multimap keys.

Comment: @user2079303: It was my second Q, (and I did the mistake to ask 2 Q at once, so only one answer :( ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract the value part of the `std::pair` in the hash map and put it into the vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using Map = std::unordered_multimap<int, int>;
    auto m = Map { {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6} };

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(m.size());

    for (auto const& elem : m)
        v.push_back(elem.second);

    for (auto const& elem : v)
        std::cout << elem << "\n";
}
```

Note that with C++11, you can use a ranged for-loop + `auto` to avoid having to explicitly express the type of the map elements. Furthermore, you can use the initializer-list syntax to quickly init the map as well.

**NOTE**: in practical examples, please do use the `reserve()` on the vector so as to avoid excessive memory allocations.

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5db318b02e1f15b).

Comment: @Jarod42 I sometimes go overboard with STL algorithms. Up to 2 functions is not a raw loop, even according to Sean Parent ;-)

Comment: Why did you change your original answer with the `for_each` and `back_inserter`?

Comment: @Sambuca because it was overkill. in general, I prefer the ["no raw loop"](https://github.com/sean-parent/sean-parent.github.com/wiki/presentations/2013-09-11-cpp-seasoning/cpp-seasoning.pdf) (slide 39) but STL algorithm approach. But anything as simple as `f(g(x))`, `f(x); g(x)` or `f(x) + g(x)` is not considered a raw loop. The range-for is the most compact way of doing this simple task.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if there was a way to just directly copy the memory without having to actually traverse the whole thing. But, I guess this solution will have to do...

Comment: @LuisYanes a hash map does not have contiguous memory layout, so you need to follow the iterators

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(lookup.size()); // optimization (allocate enough memory for all elements)

std::transform(std::begin(lookup), std::end(lookup), std::back_inserter(v),
    [](const std::pair<uint, T>& p) { return p.second; });
```

Comment: I suggest to write it with std::begin and std::end free functions since C++11 :)

Comment: @GermánDiago ok, it's probably not worth arguing over taste, but how is an algorithm + lambda + back_inserter + explicit typing more elegant than range-for loop + auto?

Comment: Note that most of the `std::`-qualifications are unnecessary, due to argument-dependent lookup.

Comment: @TemplateRex the back inserter is not needed thats a mistake. Named algorithms clarify the intent more than a for loop IMHO.

Comment: @GermánDiago in general, yes, but for simple (where simple is <= 2 function calls) loops/transforms, a range-for is simpler and cleaner. See [Sean Parent's](https://github.com/sean-parent/sean-parent.github.com/wiki/presentations/2013-09-11-cpp-seasoning/cpp-seasoning.pdf) recommendation (slide 39, which is page 102 in the pdf)

Comment: @TemplateRex Well, I saw it. My opinion is that both are readable but reading a name is very clean. I dont mean it is really shorter or better. Both are ok, I prefer transform :)

Answer (score 1):

use a loop to `push_back` the items in the vector. Of course, it require the type T to be copy constructible:

```
for ( auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++)
    v.push_back(it->second);
```

for a more refined solution, you can optimize a bit by using `reserve` to prepare enough space in the vector before that. Also, if you are going to throw away the map after that you can try to avoid copying the items but move them in instead:

```
v.reserve(map.size());
for ( auto it = map.begin(); it!= map.end(); it++)
    v.emplace_back(std::move(it->second));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying around with C++11 lately. Here's something I came up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    typedef std::unordered_multimap<int, int> MapType;

    MapType m { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 1 } };
    std::for_each(begin(m), end(m), [&](MapType::value_type i){v.push_back(i.second); });
    std::copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

**[Run my code online.](http://ideone.com/MOaUtf)**

Admittedly this approach using STL algorithms is a bit of an overkill for this problem.

Comment: Why mixin `for_each` and *for range* ?

Comment: As I said I've been trying around with C++11 features - no particular reason. The OPs question was just similar to something I had already running in my Test project.

Comment: if you use C++11, make sure to use initializer-lists.

Comment: Agree with @Jarod42 here: range-for would eliminate the iterator + lambda altogether, and it allows the use of `auto` to denote the map's element type (and for which you need C++1y to do it in a lambda)

Comment: @TemplateRex Yeah that's true. Your final answer is pretty neat :)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be: [caution untested]

```
template <typename Map>
std::vector<typename Map::mapped_type> extract_values(Map const& m) {
    std::vector<typename Map::mapped_type> v;
    v.reserve(m.size());
    std::for_each(std::begin(m), std::end(m), [&](typename Map::const_reference p)
        { v.push_back(p.second); }
    );
    return v;
}
```

Even simpler:

```
template <typename Map>
std::vector<typename Map::mapped_type> extract_values(Map const& m) {
    std::vector<typename Map::mapped_type> v;
    v.reserve(m.size());
    for(auto& p : m)
        v.push_back(p.second);
    return v;
}
```